# Using an existing telephone system with Skype home service

Tags: skype, voip, phone

I'm interested in migrating my current telco-based phone service to a more affordable VOIP solution. Because of this, I've decided to settle on Skype, which I've used for years and has been my choice as my primary desktop VOIP application.

Currently in my home I have a standard phone system that plugs directly into a telephone jack, with 4 wireless handsets. Because I already have this system, I would prefer not to replace it with a different system that's offered for sale in the Skype shop.

My ideal solution would be to purchase an adapter (or some sort of box) that goes between my modem and my existing telephone, to allow my current phone to ring when I receive a Skype call, or allow me to make outgoing calls using my Skype account. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything like this for a home environment, everything that I see is more directed towards office environments.

Does such a product exist, and if so, where can I find out more information about it and/or purchase it?

Comment: What you want isn't going to be possible because Skype is a closed system so an apater isn't going to exist.

Comment: I'm looking for some sort of hardware adapter to allow me to use my current phone system with Skype - I already know which solution I want I just don't know if the hardware exists to make it work. @Ramhound, has Skype ever sold their own hardware adapter? It seems like a very common problem (wanting to retain your current phone when using VOIP)

Comment: @John - There is no hardware adapter that does what you want.  Skype system is closed always has been.  Cisco ( whom supplies VOIP products of their own ) even complains the fact it is closed is unfair to them.  The funny thing about that is the fact Cisco's system is also closed.